Docker Desktop - WSL distro termined abruptly
I'm on Windows 10 with Docker Desktop and I get this error every time i'm trying to create the image from this dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04

# Instala paquetes necesarios
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.8 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3 \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

RUN python3 --version

This is the error i get:

By the way, this information could be useful:
wsl --status
Distribución predeterminada: Ubuntu
Versión predeterminada: 2

wsl --version
Versión de WSL: 2.1.5.0
Versión de kernel: 5.15.146.1-2
Versión de WSLg: 1.0.60
Versión de MSRDC: 1.2.5105
Versión de Direct3D: 1.611.1-81528511
Versión DXCore: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Versión de Windows: 10.0.19045.4291

wsl --list
Distribuciones de subsistema de Windows para Linux:
Ubuntu (predeterminado)
docker-desktop
docker-desktop-data

And these are my Windows features (I have highlighted features that I think might be important):

How to solve it to create the image with no problem?
